# Error in Dependency Injection when I try minify angular app

Tags: angularjs, bundle, angularjs-injector

I have done a web application based in ASP MVC and angularJS, and everything works fine. Now, I want deploy it. In my `bundleConfig` I have put `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` to minified my scripts.

When I launch the app get a error:

> Module 'dataService' is not available! You either misspelled...

In docs I have seen an interesting thing (it fits to error):

> Careful: If you plan to minify your code, your service names will get renamed and break your app.

As docs suggests I use Inline Array Annotation. My code is:

```
app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'kendo.directives', 'dataService', 'LoginFactory', 'globalService']);
```

in module *dataService* is:

```
app.service('dataService', ['$http', function($http) {
  // service logic
}]);
```

I thought that would fix the error, but not.

PS: I have seen 3 differents methods of injection dependencies and I have used all. In example I use that because in [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) is marked like *preferred*

Comment: Your first example expects a **module** `dataService`, your second one defines a **service** `dataService`. Do you have a module named `dataService`?

Comment: BTW, there is no Service() method in module.

Comment: @zeroflagL  I don't think you understand. In first code I create module app and I declare the dependencie with 'dataService'. In second code, I create 'dataService' service. As in [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), I think ...

Comment: `angular.module("MyApp"` creates the **module** `MyApp` which depends on other **modules**. `ui.router` is a **module**, `ui.bootstrap` is a **module**. If `app` in the second example is the same module as `app` in the first one then you are done. Remove `dataService` from the first one. Maybe you should look at someone's scores before you decide to write _"I don't think you understand"_.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I wanted say that "I think that I don't understand you". My english is deplorable, I didn't want offend you.
You are right, I had to remove 'dataService' in first example. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

replace `app.Service` with `app.service`.

Comment: Sorry, this is a grammar error. I correct now. But that error would cause the application doesn't work before minification, and as I mentioned the app works fine.